# Spring Boot JPA SQL statements

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use the Spring Boot and JPA. Spring Boot version is 1.5.7.RELEASE.

Here is something confused me. How can I do with this to make it working as I expect to? Thanks

The UserRepository interface：

```
package cn.alittler.cms.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import cn.alittler.cms.domain.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

The test class：

```
package cn.alittler.cms.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import cn.alittler.cms.repository.UserRepository;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserTests {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    // three SQL statements: select、select and update. Why not two, the select and update SQL statements?
    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(1L);
        user.setName("Tom");
        user.setCreateTime(new Date());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    // Two SQL statements: select and update. Why not just one, the update SQL statement?
    @Test
    public void testUpdate2() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(2L);
        user.setName("Tomi");
        user.setCreateTime(new Date());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    // Two SQL statements: select and delete. Why not just one, the delete SQL statement?
    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        userRepository.delete(2L);
    }

}
```

The first test method testUpdate(), there are three sql statements, Why not two, the select and update?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.create_time as create_t2_0_0_,
        user0_.name as name3_0_0_ 
    from
        alittler_cms_user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.create_time as create_t2_0_0_,
        user0_.name as name3_0_0_ 
    from
        alittler_cms_user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        alittler_cms_user 
    set
        create_time=?,
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
```

The second test method testUpdate2(), there are two sql statements, Why not just

one, the update statement?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.create_time as create_t2_0_0_,
        user0_.name as name3_0_0_ 
    from
        alittler_cms_user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        alittler_cms_user 
    set
        create_time=?,
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
```

The last test method testDelete(), there are also two sql statements, Why not just one, the delete sql statement?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.create_time as create_t2_0_0_,
        user0_.name as name3_0_0_ 
    from
        alittler_cms_user user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        alittler_cms_user 
    where
        id=?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because you use JPA and your test is non transactional. For a delete hibernate needs to know the entity and the relations it needs to delete hence the select. The others are because of the id a merge is done, which means the state of the db and in memory are merged (a select is done to retrieve the db state) and afterwards it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Transactional` annotation for tests, because without this annotation there is no persistence context and Hibernate tries to read entity before saving to check if it exists. When you add `@Transactional`, Hibernate performs select query `User user = userRepository.findOne(1L)` and saves entity to persistence context and don't need to perform additional select query

Comment: If I add @Transactional annotation for test class or tests method，there is no update or delete SQL statement executed，only select SQL.